# precalculus absolute value of imaginary numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question:
Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers such that $|2z - w| = 25$, $|z + 2w| = 5$, and $|z + w| = 2$. Find $|z|$.

Attempt at Solution: 
Knowing that $w$ and $z$ are complex numbers is making what I'm solving for difficult to understand. Working without substituting the $a+bi$ thing in is giving me some "wait, what" moments.
I used the given hint "Use the identity $k \cdot \overline{k} = |k|^2$" with the given equations as follows:
$$(|2z - w| = 25)^2$$$$4z^2 - 4wz + w^2 = 625$$
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: That's not the right LHS, it should be $(2 z - w)(2 \bar z - \bar w)\,$.

Comment: Well, basically you want $z\overline z$. Squaring your three equations you get three linear equations in three unknowns (namely $z\overline z,w\overline w, (z\overline w +w\overline z)$).  Now just solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That hint is wrong as written. If you square both sides of that equation then you get $$625 = |2z-w|^2 = (2z-w)(2\bar z-\bar w) = 4|z|^2+|w|^2 - 2(z\bar w+\bar zw) $$

Similarly squaring both sides of $|z+2w| = 5$ gives $$ 25 = (z+2w)(\bar z+2\bar w) = |z|^2+4|w|^2 +2(z\bar w+\bar z w)$$ and the third equation gives $$ 4 \ =(z+w)(\bar z+\bar w) = |z|^2+|w|^2+(z\bar w+\bar z w).$$

Now can you think of a way to combine these three equations to get $|z|$?

(Further hint: don't be thrown off by all the variables. As lulu mentioned in the comments, everything is in terms of three quantities: $|z|^2$, $|w|^2$ and $(z\bar w+\bar z w) $ which you can just rename $a$, $b$, and $c$ and solve for $a.$)

Comment: how come i got a=9, b=7, and c=-126?

Comment: @clache547 $|z| = 9,$ $|w|=7$ and $(z\bar w+\bar z w) = -126$ looks like the solution to that system, so you probably got it cause you solved the system right. $z = 9$ and $w = -7$ is a valid solution to the original equations (though there is a whole family of complex solutions, all satisfying $|z| = 9,$ $|w|=7$, and $(z\bar w+\bar z w) = -126$)

Comment: i need a little help on how to continue

Comment: @clache547 You're done. $|z| = 9.$ Remember, $a$ was just a name you were calling $|z|$